# How to compare two columns in csv with two values declared before in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

the catalog there this values:

```
0.6881  -55.0099
0.6883  -80.3465
0.7827  -59.5199
0.8206  -54.5565
0.8418  -49.7932
0.9503  -43.6182
1.0236  -52.9165
1.0488  -50.6465
1.1068  -50.6182
1.134   -32.2499
1.1325  -45.4482
1.2633  -27.7416
1.2725  -50.8282
1.3115  -40.6049
1.3461  -30.5649
...
...
```

and my values declared before is ra = 59.6517601 dec = 61.5475502. How compare to show if there values ra, dec in my catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for help to answer my question and sorry for my delay to answer here! Well, I find a simple solution for this. I'm working with fits files.

```
catalogue = pd.read_csv('cat7.csv', delimiter=(','))
catalogue.columns = ['ra', 'dec']
df1 = catalogue[['ra','dec']]

ra = []
dec = []

for r in df1['ra']:
    ra.append(r)

for d in df1['dec']:
    dec.append(d)

for filename in os.listdir('6df'):
    print('reading file ' + filename)
    if filename.endswith('.fits'):
        hdulist = fits.open('6df/' + filename)
        try:
            ra1  = hdulist[2].header['ra']
            dec1 = hdulist[2].header['dec']


            for i in range(0, len(df1)):
                if (int(ra1) == int(ra[i]) and int(dec1) == int(dec[i])):
                    shutil.copy('6df/' + filename, 'type/' + filename)
                    print(filename + ' copiado')
                    break
        except:
            shutil.copy('6df/' + filename, 'SEM_RA_DEC/' + filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

First create the catalogue in python:

```
l = '0.6881 -55.0099 0.6883 -80.3465 0.7827 -59.5199 0.8206 -54.5565 0.8418 -49.7932 0.9503 -43.6182 1.0236 -52.9165 1.0488 -50.6465 1.1068 -50.6182 1.134 -32.2499 1.1325 -45.4482 1.2633 -27.7416 1.2725 -50.8282 1.3115 -40.6049 1.3461 -30.5649'

l = l.replace(' ', ',')
l = l.split(',')
l = [float(a) for a in l]

ra = 59.6517601
dec = 61.5475502

ra in l
dec in l
```

Both output False, so neither ra or dec are on the list.
Imagine ra was in the list, then:

```
l.append(ra)
ra in l
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Before anything, if the decimals of `ra` and `dec` are different from those of your values in csv file, use `round()` to fix the decimals first, then do the following action

using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas

ra = 59.6517601
dec = 61.5475502
pattern = [ra,dec]

table = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
for ind,row in table.iterrows():
    if list(row.values)==pattern:
        print('pattern was detected at index {}'.format(ind))
```

and without pandas:

```
cnt = 0

ra = 59.6517601
dec = 61.5475502
pattern = [ra,dec]

with open('file.csv','r').read() as file:
    for row in file.split('\n'):
        x = [float(row.split(',')[0]),float(row.split(',')[1])]
        if x==pattern:
            print('pattern was detected at index {}'.format(cnt))
            break
    cnt += 1
```

just remember that if you come into `ValueError` in the second solution, it is likely because of the `split` behavior for text in files, where an empty element is created at last index of the list. to avoid the error, do:

`file = file[:-1]` after the `with` syntax